# Use interface signals as inout in systemverilog

Tags: system-verilog

What is the proper way to use same signals of an interface as input or output?
I am aware that the way i am doing, could end up with X since because there is no restrictions in the use of the signals from the interface.

So what is the way to do this using the modports?

Code,
Use signals as input or input or output of the same interface

Interfaces:

```
interface tx_bfm();
  logic clk;
  logic ch;
  logic [7:0] data;
  
  modport tx_mst(output clk, ch, data);
  modport tx_slv(input clk, ch, output data);
  
  always @(posedge clk)
    if(ch)
      data = data + 1;
    else
      data = 0;

endinterface

interface rx_bfm();
  logic clk;
  logic ch;
  logic [7:0] data;
  bit [7:0] data_q [$];
  
  modport rx_mst(output clk, ch, input data);
  modport rx_slv(input clk, ch, data);
  
  always @(posedge clk)
    data_q.push_back(data);
    
endinterface
```

Module to test the interfaces and connections

```
module tb;
  
  bit clk;
  
  /** Clk signal **/
  always #1 clk = ~clk;
  
  /** Instance for Interfaces **/
  tx_bfm tx_bfm0();
  rx_bfm rx_bfm0();
  
  /** Using tx_bfm as master without modport**/
  /*
  assign tx_bfm0.clk = clk; 
  assign rx_bfm0.clk = tx_bfm0.clk; 
  assign rx_bfm0.ch = tx_bfm0.ch;
  */
  
  /** Using rx_bfm as master without modport**/
  assign rx_bfm0.clk = clk; 
  assign tx_bfm0.clk = rx_bfm0.clk; 
  assign tx_bfm0.ch = rx_bfm0.ch;
  
  /** Trying to use modports for tx_bfm **/
  //tx_bfm.tx_mst tx_bfm_mst0();//
  
  initial begin
    $display("::-- Testing --::");
    
    /** Trying to use modports for tx_bfm **/
    //tx_bfm_mst0.clk = clk;
    //tx_bfm_mst0.ch = 1;
    
    #10 $finish;
  end
  
endmodule
```

Comment: When used alone in a testbench, the modports have no meaning.  An interface is a bunch of wires.  Your testbench has two bunches of wires.  Modports have meaning when used as a type of a module port.  In this context (as a module port) it makes sense to define driving-output-manager ports and receiving-input-subordinate ports.   There is little to no reason to use modports in a testbench.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are confused  about interfaces. They primary purpose of an interface is to provide connection between different modules, in other words, to be passed as ports to modules. The point of modports is to create a specific view of interface signals for a particular module.

In the following example interface contains a single field 'data';
modports create two views:

- data is input (slave)
- data is output (master)

There are two modules:

- slave, which consumes data
- master, which produces data

The interface 'intf' is used to pass data between modules. The modport 'master' is used to connect to the 'master' module and presents its field as 'output' to the module via modport. Similarly the 'slave' modports makes its 'data' an input to the 'slave' module.

```
interface IF ;
   logic data;
   modport master(output data);
   modport slave(input data);
endinterface

module tb;
  IF intf();
   
   master master(intf.master);
   slave slave(intf.slave);
endmodule

module master(IF.master intf); // can use just IF
  logic tmpData;
   always_comb
     intf.data = tmpData;
endmodule

module slave(IF.slave intf); // can use just IF
   logic tmpData;
   always_comb
      tmpData = intf.data;
endmodule
```

Comment: Thank you. If I use just IF the module will figure out what is the modport for the signal? e.g. module slave (IF intf); tmpData = intf.data;

Comment: Yes, the compiler will figure it out.

Comment: In your example. module master(IF.master intf); Why intf.data = tmpData; if intf.data is an output? I mean shouldn't this be: tmpData = into.data;

Comment: in master, intf.data is an output of the module master. Therefore, it is assigned to. modport defines directions of the ports in the **module**, not in the *interface*. it has nothing to do with interface itself.

Comment: How can I re-use a module with different interface? The fact that I code the module with an specific interface limits it's use with another interface. Is there a way to re-use the same module? For example the master?

Comment: i do not understand your question. You can instantiate the interface multiple times and instantiate modules using different instances of interfaces with different modules. But you cannot change the type of the interface, as with any type of a port (unless you use parametrized modules with type parameters). But this is outside of this question chain and you should ask a different question.

Comment: Alright. I am testing your code and I found that intf.data = tmpData can also be used as tmpData  = intf.data. The compiler doesn't show any errors for the master, but shows error for the slave ('Input ports cannot be driven'). Why this flexibility for outputs? Is this a inconsistency, a bug in the compilers? https://www.edaplayground.com/x/8f_M

Comment: interesting. i've found that at least vcs gives an error message if you declare the port as IF.slave and does not otherwise (however, it complains about multiple drivers for data in this case).